# Show that a continuous map $f: S^n \to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to show that if $n>1$ then any continuous map $f: S^n\to S^1$ is nullhomotopic.

I can only prove this when f is not surjective. I guess this has something to do with the fact that $\pi_1(S^n)$ is trival for $n\geqslant2$ but I can't see how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $S^n$ is simply connected for $n\ge2$, so $f:S^n\to S^1$ lifts to a map from $S^n$ to the universal covering of $S^1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer by Lord Shark the Unknown in more detail.

Leaving basepoints implicit, the lifting criterion for covering maps gives you that for any covering space $p:\widetilde{X}\to X$ and a map $f:Y\to X$, with $Y$ path connected and locally path connected, then a lift $\tilde{f}:Y\to \widetilde{X}$ exists if and only if $f_*(\pi_1(Y))\subset p_*(\pi_1(\widetilde{X}))$.

For the simply connected cover, $\pi_1(\widetilde{X})\cong 0$, and hence a lift exists provided $f_*(\pi_1(Y))\cong 0$, which is trivially satisfied if $Y$ is simply connected. Taking $Y=S^n$, $X=S^1$ and $\widetilde{X}=2\pi i\mathbb{R}\overset{\rm exp}{\longrightarrow}S^1$ the universal cover of $S^1$ gives you a lift $\widetilde{f}:S^n\to 2\pi i \mathbb{R}$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is contractible, you can choose a nullhomotopy for $\tilde{f}$, which (after post-composing with ${\rm exp}$) will induce a nullhomotopy for $f$.

Comment: It's a bit dangerous to "leave base points implicit", usually. I would not recommend for OP to take the habit until they are sure they can tell when it is or is not a problem.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi In general, I'm inclined to agree with you. However, in this situation there is no danger since for a path connected space $\pi_1$ only depends on the chosen basepoint up to isomorphism. In any case, the OP has been warned.